# LBYouTubeExtractor is it deprecated?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api

I have used "LBYouTubeExtractor" to play YouTube videos inside my application but right now while I am checking the same app it doesn't play the videos. While debugging I came to know that I am getting error in below code for all valid URL's.

```html
extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error)
```

Is "LBYouTubeExtractor" has been deprecated? If so do you have any alternative solution to play youtube video inside your app? Kindly suggest a best method to proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper